# A database. One field. An html dynamic table. Can't extract a limited amount of data

Tags: php, html, mysql

[image]I want to copy part of a database field and insert it into an html dynamic table (by dynamic I mean that the number of rows grows depending from the amount of rows in the database table).
Let's say that I already limited the width of the cell in the html table in which I want to insert the data by a certain percentage of width.
The problem lies in the copying. How can I copy the necessary amount of symbols so that it won't make my cell grow in height but stay only in a height equal to one line? Before copying, I want to ensure that there is "..." at the end of the line, right where I cut the text.
One important detail. I'm working both with russian and english language here.
My database fields that have text have "utf8-general-ci" collation. But I already use mysqli_set_charset and set cp1251 when ENTERING data into my database and mysqli_set_charset with utf8 when READING data from it.

Here is the php file where I am trying to read the data into the html table. Hope you can help me. Especially with the encoding problem. The current php file makes a � symbol at the end of the line, which is very troubling.

```
    <?php
  include_once 'Connection.php';
  ?>


 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        table, th {
        border: 1px solid black;
       }
    </style>
</head>



<body>
    <h1 style="Text-align: center;">Существующие работы </h1><br><br><br>

<table style="width:100%">
     <tr>
        <th style="width:13%">Работодатель</th>
        <th>Описание работы</th>
        <th style="width:8%">Оплата</th>
        <th style="width:8%">Количество людей</th>
        <th style="width:10%">Срочность</th>
        <th style="width:8%">Сложность</th>     
        </tr>
   </table>


 <?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM request_data;";
    $conn = Connect();
    mysqli_set_charset($conn,'utf8');
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($resultCheck > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo '<table style = "width:100%">
            <tr>
              <th style="width:13%">'.$row['ID'].'</th>
              <th>'.substr($row['The_Job'],0,145).'...'.'</th>
              <th style="width:8%">'.$row['Paymentfro'].'-'.$row['Paymentto'].'</th>
              <th style="width:8%">'.$row['Amount'].'</th>
              <th style="width:10%">'.$row['Urgency'].'</th>
              <th style="width:8%">'.$row['Difficulty'].'</th>      
            </tr>
          </table>';
    }
   }

  ?>

 </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: As you can see, the largest cell is the one with wich I am having trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be achieved with css (don't need `substr` nor `mb_substr`, let css add ellipses).

For that second `td`, you add a `class` defined as:

```
<style>
.job-detail {
    width: 53%; /* change this to the width you need */
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
</style>
```

That will do the automatic ellipsis when that one cell reaches beyond the bounds.

And then set the class on your `td`:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo '<tr>
          <td style="width:13%">'. $row['ID'] .'</td>
          <td class="job-detail">'. $row['The_Job'] .'</td>
          <td style="width:8%">'. $row['Paymentfro'] .'-'.$row['Paymentto'].'</td>
          <td style="width:8%">'. $row['Amount'] .'</td>
          <td style="width:10%">'. $row['Urgency'] .'</td>
          <td style="width:8%">'. $row['Difficulty'] .'</td>      
        </tr>';
}
```

**NOTE** Your second question about encoding, should be made as a second question since it is entirely unrelated to your first question.

Answer (score 0):

You created table again and again. create rows for each record.

```
<?php
    function table_view(){
        include_once 'Connection.php';

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM request_data;";
        $conn = Connect();
        mysqli_set_charset($conn,'utf8');
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if ($resultCheck > 0) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                echo '<tr>
                   <th style="width:13%">'.$row['ID'].'</th>
                   <th>'.substr($row['The_Job'],0,145).'...'.'</th>
                   <th style="width:8%">'.$row['Paymentfro'].'-'.$row['Paymentto'].'</th>
                   <th style="width:8%">'.$row['Amount'].'</th>
                   <th style="width:10%">'.$row['Urgency'].'</th>
                   <th style="width:8%">'.$row['Difficulty'].'</th>      
                 </tr>';
             }
         }

    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style>
            table, th {
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 style="Text-align: center;">Существующие работы </h1><br><br><br>
        <table style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                <th style="width:13%">Работодатель</th>
                <th>Описание работы</th>
                <th style="width:8%">Оплата</th>
                <th style="width:8%">Количество людей</th>
                <th style="width:10%">Срочность</th>
                <th style="width:8%">Сложность</th>     
            </tr>
            <?php table_view(); ?>
        </table>
    </body>
 </html>
```